# Is it possible to create a DataSnap project in Delphi 10.3.3 Community Edition?

Tags: delphi, datasnap, delphi-10.3-rio

Is it possible to create a DataSnap project in Delphi 10.3.3 Community Edition?
I could not find the Web > DataSnap project.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Feature Matrix](https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/Delphi-Feature-Matrix.pdf), DataSnap’s WebBroker library requires the Professional edition or higher, and all other DataSnap features require the Enterprise edition or higher.

Comment: Has this changed with 11.3? It's my understanding that the difference between Community and Professional today is licensing.